# Javascript testing with stubbing

Tags: javascript, sinon

I have this function

```
export const getBigData = (param) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    reqwestWrapper.post({
      url,
      data: {"someKey": "someData"},
      success: (result) => {
        resolve(result.data);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I am trying to write a test to assert .post is being called with right value so I have test as

```
let url = 'some-url',
    data = {},
    successCallback = sinon.stub();

expect(reqwest.post).calledWith({url, data, successCallback})
```

But test is failing saying expected argument is not match.

```
AssertionError: expected post to have been called with arguments { data: {  }, successCallback: function stub() {}, url: "some-url" }
post({ data: {  }, success: function success() {}, url: "some-url" })
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What's someData and someKey? If it's a string, the correct is `{"someKey": "someData"}`

Comment: yes they are string. Update in the code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not actually call `request.post` in the provided code. You just set up the test of the call. Before the test you need to do:

```
reqest.post({url, data, successCallback});
```